# Создание нового массива на основе полученных данных

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста, есть участок кода 
System.out.println(time_array[i]);
который выводит несколько значений, как отталкиваясь от этого создать новый масcив из этих значений ?

```
         {  
            if (Voltage_array[i] <= 0.9)                      
            {               
                period = true;
            }         
            if (Voltage_array[i] > 0.9 & period) 
            {   


               System.out.println(time_array[i]);      
               period = false;  
            }
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: Чем массив `time_array` не устраивает вас как есть?

Comment: массив time_array имеет несколько тысяч значений, а у меня в определенные моменты выводятся несколько < 20 значений из этого массива, нужно из них создать новый, чтоб потом можно было проводить с ним операции

Comment: Заведите любую коллекцию(тот же Vector, например) и добавляйте туда нужные элементы.

Comment: Vector "плохой" - он синхронизован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List</*Нужный тип*/> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Нужные элементы добавляйте так

```
list.add(time_array[i]);
```

Получить значение можно так

```
list.get(index);
```

И будет у вас динамический массив, с размером которого не надо париться.

Comment: Спасибо огромное !!!